# How do I use labels in address calculations

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86-64

I have the following snippet of inline assembly:

```
procedure Foo;
asm
//.....
@partialloop: shr rdx,1              //every instruction is 4 bytes
              lea r11,[rip + (7*4)+(@partial-@offset)]
@offset:      sub r11,rdx
              xor r8,r8
              jmp r11                //do a partial loop
@loop64:      mov [rcx],rax
@partial:     mov [rcx+08H],rax
//....
end;
```

The compiler does not accept this syntax:

> E2105 Inline assembler syntax error

Create use of `offset`, `ptr` or `@@` does not help.

What syntax do I need to use to make this compile?

Comment: Hand assemble it and write it with db statements

Comment: No. If you want it to go faster why not?

Comment: Oh you mean outside of delphi using Masm and then copy paste.

Comment: Something like that would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work, because there is no need for this construct.
The compiler disallows these constructs to prevent logical errors in code.

The following snippet is actually correct:

```
@partialloop: shr rdx,1              //every instruction is 4 bytes
              lea r11,[rip + @partial + (7*4)] //r11= end of the loop
@offset:      sub r11,rdx            //step back as needed
              xor r8,r8              //only do a single iteration
              jmp r11                //do a partial loop
@loop64:      mov [rcx],rax
@partial:     mov [rcx+08H],rax
//....
end;
```

The expression: `[rip + @partial + (4*7)]` evaluates as follows:

- rip (the IP after this instruction).
- @partial the distance between rip and that label.
- (7*4) an addition offset on top of everything else

Using a `@label` in calculations always yields an offset, not an absolute value. A `jmp @label` always translates into a relative jump, never an absolute jmp.

The original statement (if allowed by the compiler) would of course also be correct:

```
lea r11,[rip + (7*4)+(@partial-@offset)]
r11 = rip($6B74FB) + 28 + @partial($0C) - @offset(0)
```

But because RIP is already equal to the absolute address of @offset there is no need to include it twice.

Comment: The syntax for RIP-relative is often confusing / ambiguous across different flavours of ASM, for the reasons you explain.  In NASM syntax, a label is just a symbol with a value which happens to be an address instead of something you define with `myvar equ 0x123`.  So writing `[rip + label]` uses the absolute address as an offset.  In NASM syntax, you'd write `[rel label + 7*4]`, or just `[label + 7*4]` if you used a `DEFAULT REL` directive.  You might want to write `[rip+@partial  + (7*4)]` to make it more clear that it's just an offset from a label, not address math.

Comment: Speaking of address-math, as I commented on J's answer, NASM has no problem subtracting non-extern labels.  Does Delphi let you write `mov ecx, @partial - @offset`?  The language would have to accept/reject such expressions depending on whether the label was defined in the current compilation unit or not, which they probably decided was more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @PeterCordes, no it does not. `E2105 Inline assembler syntax error`

Comment: @PeterCordes No, it does not.  The rules are very clear, as per the references in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Label addresses are relocatable and [operations on them are restricted to **addition and subtraction of constants**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Assembly_Expressions#Expression_Classes).

> A relocatable expression denotes a value that requires relocation at link time, while an absolute expression denotes a value that requires no such relocation. Typically, expressions that refer to **labels**, variables, procedures, or functions are relocatable, **since the final address of these symbols is unknown at compile time**.

further:

> The built-in assembler allows you to carry out any operation on an absolute value, but it restricts operations on relocatable values to addition and subtraction of constants.

You can add a label address (relocatable value) to a constant but you cannot *subtract* a relocatable value **from** a constant.  You also cannot add two relocatable values  together.

In brief, it just cannot be done.

Comment: You're talking about link-time math, which is impossible.  What *is* possible in normal assembly (e.g. NASM) is expressions involving the difference between labels that are both *defined* in the current asm input file.  The final addresses aren't known until link time, but the difference is known to the assembler.  e.g. `mov ecx, label2 - label1` assembles to  `b9 22 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0x22` in the test I just did with `yasm`.  The assembler knows the exact layout of memory for the current compilation unit; its job is to assemble bytes into the output file, so it has to know this!

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, in this case, within a contiguous block, it *should* be possible to determine a constant difference between these two labels.  The Delphi compiler, however, treats these values as generally relocatable and will not allow such an operation.  This is not NASM, nor is it YASM - the rules are different.  Who knows what reservations the compiler authors had in mind?  I don't know.

Comment: @PeterCordes  It is conceivable that the compiler wants to reserve freedom to rearrange the code layout.  A label following a `jmp`, for example, would have no reason to follow its previous instruction in memory since execution should never flow through incrementally - the compiler may want to relocate that code section for whatever reason.  Devil's advocate, of course, I have no evidence that this actually happens, but it seems that the rules would allow it to potentially happen.

Comment: I was just pointing out that it's not fundamentally impossible, it's simply disallowed by the language rules for simplicity.  They presumably don't want it to matter whether a label is defined in the current compilation unit or not.  I also thought some readers might be interested to hear how it works in NASM.  I'm glad you took out the wording about not knowing the memory layout, because that didn't explain this case.

Comment: re: rearranging code: you mean within an inline-asm block?  That seems highly unlikely.  You can get a label address into a register and offset it if you want, to do a computed jump into the middle of a sequence of equal-sized instructions.  The syntax restriction don't stop you from knowing how instructions will assemble and doing crazy stuff.  Unless there are a lot of other rules that prohibit a lot of stuff in inline asm, the compiler can't safely break up your inline asm into separate blocks without *understanding* it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I reluctantly took it out, but the rules as defined very plainly leave open the possibility that similar assumptions about code layout are not to be taken as generally valid - perhaps not in this specific case, but certainly in the general case.  I take it to be similar to undefined behaviour in C++ - surely you can make undefined behaviour work in some cases, but it is not always guaranteed to work in all cases.  The operation is entirely restricted here in any case, but we can imagine it as such were it allowed.

Comment: Yeah, it seems appropriate to say something along those lines.  You're right that you can't assume anything about layout for labels that aren't defined in asm blocks.  I was *only* talking about making assumptions about the layout of code inside an inline asm block.  I looked over the delphi pages about asm you linked, and I didn't see any restrictions on the kinds of jumps you can do within an inline asm block.  That means the compiler can't do anything which would break computed jumps or loading code bytes as data, since that's allowed in normal asm and they don't specifically disallow it.

Comment: @PeterCordes  Agreed, like I said, it was devil's advocate stuff.  I really don't know why they restricted this - it could just be laziness and I'm thinking too hard trying to come up with a valid reason here.

Comment: I like my theory that it's because they don't distinguish between extern and non-extern labels.  Having it legal only for labels defined in the current compilation unit would mean that moving a non-asm function or array to another file could create a compile error.